prove that a set $A$ of infinite sequences of natural numbers that have a certain property is countable
The question :

Let $A$ be a set of infinite sequences of natural numbers that has this property:
For all two sequences $\{a_n\}$$\{b_n\}$ in $A$, there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t for all $n>n_0$ we have $a_n=b_n$. Prove that $A$ is countable.

What I know (or am allowed to use) is that to prove that a set is countable, it is finite or it can be made in one-to-one correspondence with the set of natural numbers.
Now what I am thinking about is that every sequence in the set is equal to each other because from the given info we have that for all two sequences there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t for all $n>n_0$ we have $a_n=b_n$ and let's say $c_n = d_n$ then we can compare $c_n$ with $a_n$. We have that $\exists n_1\in \mathbb{N} $ s.t $a_n=c_n$ and so on with the rest of the sequences we have $\exists n_k \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t all the sequences are equal, therefore, it's countable but how can I prove it?

Hint: Fix $(a_n) \in A$. For each $k$ let $A_k=\{(b_n) \in A: b_n=a_n \forall n>k\}$. Check that each $A_k$ is countable and $A=\bigcup_k A_k$.

is it safe to say that each $A_k$ is finite and hence countable?

No. $A_k$ is not finite.  Map $(b_n) \in A_k$ to $(b_1,b_2,...,b_{k-1})\subseteq \mathbb N \times \mathbb N ...\times \mathbb N$ ($k-1$ factors) to see that $A_k$ is countable.

Consider $A_1$ for example. It consists of all sequences of the form $(b_1,a_2,a_3,...)$. The first coordinate $b_1$ has countably many choices right? Why do you think it has only finitely many choices?
